# Plot Points on image opencv

Tags: opencv, mouseevent

I am try to annotate some images of my database to prepar it for a learning, i want to plot somes points on a face on images and store the coordinates, with no other lib (like Qt), i use mouse_event Opencv, for that i detect click like that:

```
using namespace openni; 

Point center;
Mat imgCurrent; 
void plotPointImg(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param = NULL)
{
    if(event =  CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
        center = Point(x,y);
        circle(imgCurrent, center,1,CV_RGB(255,0,0),3);

}
```

But, i get the coordinates all the time, it follow the mouse mouvement not the click..Any one see a solution for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP` is always equal to the event. And It seems you have some bugs in your code. Change it this way:

```
void plotPointImg(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param = NULL)
{
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        center = Point(x,y);
        circle(imgCurrent, center,1,CV_RGB(255,0,0),3);
    }
}
```

I basicly changed `=` to `==` and placed brackets. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

you're missing proper braces here, also you want == not =    ;)

```
if(event ==  CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP) // maybe buttondown is what you want ?
{
    center = Point(x,y);
    circle(imgCurrent, center,1,CV_RGB(255,0,0),3);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank yow, i get the coordinates of the mouse, but no circle on image, I seems simple i loaded an image  then called SetMouseCallBack on my window, but the circle is not on image :\ ..